# How do you make objects spawn on the same layer further forwards than others

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've coded some cannonballs in a 2d game which has a 45 degree vertical to horizontal viewpoint. They are spawned using a prefab, and then spawn an explosion prefab upon their destruction. They then are spawn on top of each other in a random order. Is there a way to set further forwards object (In my case lower in the y axis) to be further forwards in the same layer, without creating individual prefabs for each explosion with different sorting layers?

Comment: Yes, move their transform on the y axis.. to lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in way to do that, but how about attaching a script to the cannonballs that will assign the sprite renderer's "order in layer" to `-transform.y * 10` (adjust the `*10` as needed to accomodate your scale)?

Comment: Thx, I'll try that